# GA4 Data API custom dimensions don't have screenPageViews metric values

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a problem with GA4 Data API reporting.
I have created some custom dimensions and I want to get page view metrics by this custom dimensions. It has Event scope. When I send next request I just get metrics by hostName, but not by my custom event. Should I use another metric, or did I something wrong?

**Request:**

```
{"dimensions":[{"name":"eventName"},{"name":"hostName"},{"name":"customEvent:node_title"}],"metrics":[{"name":"screenPageViews"}],"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"yesterday","endDate":"today"}],"keepEmptyRows":true}
```

**Response:**
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdlAu.png)

I tried to use eventCount metric, and actually it works, but I'm not sure it correct, because hostName dimension works with screenPageViews.